# Displaying ITime values as.character in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I'm plotting a histogram of an `ITime` variable, and I want the x-axis ticks to be displayed in the `as.character` value if the x-variables. By default they are just represented as the number of seconds since 0:00. How can I accomplish this?

```
make.time <- function(x){
        mins <- sample(1:59, 1)
        if(mins < 10) mins <- paste0('0', mins)
        paste0(sample(1:23, 1), ':', mins)
}


data.table(x = sample(1:100, 50, T), 
           time = as.ITime(replicate(50, make.time()))) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(time)) + geom_histogram()
```

Comment: Are you really using `replicate()` in your real code? Because that strips off the `ITime` class information from that vector.

Comment: @MrFlick No, that's just for the example. Thanks for the tip, I edited the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in the example, the `make.time()` function isn't vecotrized. Here an alterlative implementation

```
make.time <- function(n=1){
  mins <- sample(1:59, n, replace=T)
  hrs <- sample(1:23, n, replace=T)
  as.ITime(sprintf("%d:%02f", hrs, mins))
}
```

Then the sample data is

```
dd <- data.table(x = sample(1:100, 50, T), time = make.time(50))
```

Then if you want the more traditional date/time axis labeling, you can explicitly convert to `POSIXct`

```
ggplot(dd, aes(as.POSIXct(time))) + geom_histogram()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's almost what I want. How would I remove the date part of the labels? In the real data, the rows' data are observed at various dates and I'm just trying to plot the distribution of times.

Comment: See [?scale_x_time](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html) and friends.